# react how to toggle mui ListItemIcon true/false

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, arrays, material-ui

Learning Reactjs by coding, here i have created a folder which has 'Inbox', 'Sent Items','Deleted Items', and 'Archieve' inside it when clicked, and next to those are 'StarBorder' icons, but my question is, is there a way to have those 'StarBorder' icons appear only when that spicific  section is clicked and if section has an icon and you still click it, it should hide it like hide/unhide. I dont know how to do it because those sections does not have any ID's.

https://codesandbox.io/s/nestedlist-demo-material-ui-forked-x7v31s?file=/demo.tsx

code:

```js
import * as React from "react";
import ListSubheader from "@mui/material/ListSubheader";
import List from "@mui/material/List";
import ListItemButton from "@mui/material/ListItemButton";
import ListItemIcon from "@mui/material/ListItemIcon";
import ListItemText from "@mui/material/ListItemText";
import Collapse from "@mui/material/Collapse";
import InboxIcon from "@mui/icons-material/MoveToInbox";

import ExpandLess from "@mui/icons-material/ExpandLess";
import ExpandMore from "@mui/icons-material/ExpandMore";
import StarBorder from "@mui/icons-material/StarBorder";

export default function NestedList() {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(true);

  const handleClick = () => {
    setOpen(!open);
  };

  return (
    <List
      sx={{ width: "100%", maxWidth: 360, bgcolor: "background.paper" }}
      component="nav"
      aria-labelledby="nested-list-subheader"
      subheader={
        <ListSubheader component="div" id="nested-list-subheader">
          Nested List Items
        </ListSubheader>
      }
    >
      <ListItemButton onClick={handleClick}>
        <ListItemIcon>
          <InboxIcon />
        </ListItemIcon>
        <ListItemText primary="Folder" />
        {open ? <ExpandLess /> : <ExpandMore />}
      </ListItemButton>
      <Collapse in={open} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
        <List component="div" disablePadding>
          <ListItemButton sx={{ pl: 4 }}>
            <ListItemIcon>
              <StarBorder />
            </ListItemIcon>
            <ListItemText primary="Inbox" />
          </ListItemButton>
          <ListItemButton sx={{ pl: 4 }}>
            <ListItemIcon>
              <StarBorder />
            </ListItemIcon>
            <ListItemText primary="Sent Items" />
          </ListItemButton>
          <ListItemButton sx={{ pl: 4 }}>
            <ListItemIcon>
              <StarBorder />
            </ListItemIcon>
            <ListItemText primary="Deleted Items" />
          </ListItemButton>
          <ListItemButton sx={{ pl: 4 }}>
            <ListItemIcon>
              <StarBorder />
            </ListItemIcon>
            <ListItemText primary="Archieve" />
          </ListItemButton>
        </List>
      </Collapse>
    </List>
  );
}
```

Comment: any idea is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an ID for each `<ListItemButton>` and then a handler function that updates a state which holds the selected button. Finally, conditionally render the star icon based on which item is sitting in the state

```
const handleSelected = (e) => {
    setSelected(e.currentTarget.id);
  };


<ListItemButton id={"Inbox"} onClick={handleSelected} sx={{ pl: 4 }}>
            <ListItemIcon>
              {selected === "Inbox" && <StarBorder />}
            </ListItemIcon>
            <ListItemText primary="Inbox" />
          </ListItemButton>
```

CodeSandbox : https://codesandbox.io/s/nestedlist-demo-material-ui-forked-4euc3p?file=/demo.tsx:1573-1826

Comment: thnx, can you make it so if some section has icon then you still click it, it should hide that icon , like hide and unhide

Comment: It would follow the same logic , just a different implementation . Play around with the code and I trust you'll find a solution that suits your needs. I believe in you

Comment: i fixed it like this: const handleSelected = (e) => {
    setSelected(e.currentTarget.id== selected?null:e.currentTarget.id);
  };

Comment: could you possibly answer this also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73158201/react-broken-state-from-drawimage